# Installing Connectwise

Tags: wine, mono

I'm wondering if anyone out that has been able to install ConnectWise PSA on Ubuntu?

I've got wine up and running, and I know Connectwise needs Microsoft .Net 3.5. Can I just install .Net through wine, or would I have to go the route of installing Mono, then trying to install Connectwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET framework 3.5 or 4 doesn't run under wine ([source](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2586)). Right now (March 2011) there are some big profile bugs that are not likely to be solved soon. You can try to run this program with Mono, but very likely the only realistic way to run it on linux is through virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

You could install .NET 3.5 on wine (I think it is possible with #[winetricks](http://packages.ubuntu.com/winetricks) [image: Install winetricks]), but I'm not too sure if it would result in a working product. You're probably better off using that in a virtual machine.